Simple UI that references other scripts
I have 3 relatively complex scripts that all make up part of a UI. I want to avoid combining them all into a single script, because even though this works, it's difficult to read and navigate.
I would like to have a MainUI script that references these other scripts however its proving more complicated that I thought.
To simplify the problem, I have created Simple scripts Script 1,2 and 3.py and Main UI.py
Script1
def main():
    return "Hello"

Script2
def main():
    return "How are you"

Script3:
def main():
    return "Bye"

MainUI:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Import scripts
import script1
import script2
import script3

class MainUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Main UI with Dropdown")
        self.geometry("300x200")

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Select a script from the dropdown")
        self.label.pack(pady=10)

        self.selected_script = tk.StringVar()
        self.dropdown = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=self.selected_script)
        self.dropdown['values'] = ("1", "2", "3")
        self.dropdown.pack(pady=10)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Run Script", command=self.run_script)
        self.button.pack(pady=10)

        self.output_label = tk.Label(self, text="", wraplength=250)
        self.output_label.pack(pady=10)

    def run_script(self):
        script = self.selected_script.get()
        if script == "1":
            result = script1.main()
        elif script == "2":
            result = script2.main()
        elif script == "3":
            result = script3.main()
        else:
            result = "Select a valid script from the dropdown"
        
        self.output_label.config(text=result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainUI()
    app.mainloop()

Running MainUI however I get the error AttributeError: module 'script1' has no attribute 'main'.
I am pretty new to developing UIs using code or tkiner. I don't need anything fancy and so this seemed appropriate.

If anyone familiar with developing UIs could advise on best practices that and advice on how to get this to work that would be really useful.

Cannot reproduce the error.

I have just tried something similar and it works correctly. Are you sure the code you showed aboved is actually saved in your scripts?

Oh my gosh, yes you are right. I didn't even save the file. wow haha.
